# Modificar "ExpireTimeSpan" Net Core Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, cookies

estoy tratando de poder saber como poder editar esta propiedad luego de que el sitio arranque, el contexto seria poder renovar el tiempo de expiración cada vez que el usuario realice cierta acción, todo esto controlado mediante un eventListener en JavaScript que luego haga un llamada Ajax a una acción de controlador que modifique la propiedad "ExpireTimeSpan".

Dejo el codigo tanto de JavaScript donde monitoreo la inactividad y la configuración del TimeSpan

Net-Core:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuth").AddCookie("CookieAuth", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "CookieAuth";
    options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/AccesoRestringido";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    //options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
 
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin",
        policy => policy.RequireClaim("USUARIO.PER_CODIGO", "ADM"));
});
```

Javascript:

```
function now() {
    return Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
}

var agregado = 60;//valor en segundos
var time = now() + agregado;
var ruta = window.location.pathname;
addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    time = now() + agregado
});

let interval = setInterval(e => {
    var now1 = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    if (now() >= time && ruta != "/Public/IngresarRequerimiento") {
        window.location.assign("/User/Logout_Inactividad");

    }
}, 1000);
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Has considerado el uso de variables globales?

Comment: No estimado, pero no me queda claro en que podría facilitarme eso en lo que busco.

Comment: olvídalo, mejor dale una revisada a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41872895/3613462 se relaciona.

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx le daré una revisada